# Seeing small dashes under Button's title in Xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, xcode8

I was creating a simple app in Xcode 8.1 with swift 3 and I got this problem (picture): dashes under buttons symbols.
How can I fix this issue?
[image: dashes (-) under (+, -, *, /)]
Thanks.

Comment: Kindly check your Outlet connections, their might be chances that ant one of them causing the issue.If not analyse the crash log and include it as part of your question so that we can suggest you based on that.

Comment: You need to check button style on your iPhone device's setting. To check please go to General -> Accessibility -> Button Shapes. If it is enabled, then make it disable and run the app again. It'll hide the underlines from buttons.

Comment: are you setting Attributed text to button title?

Comment: Ronak Chaniyara no, I am setting it to plain.

Comment: Nirmit Dagly absolutely you are right. wow thank you. well done.

Answer (score 0):

So Nirmit dagly  (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3401707/nirmit-dagly) has given the exact solution and it works perfectly.
He says: "You need to check button style on your iPhone device's setting. To check please go to General -> Accessibility -> Button Shapes. If it is enabled, then make it disable and run the app again. It'll hide the underlines from buttons."
I do thank him for his helpful answer and I has republish it here for the benefit of others.
Thank you again Nirmit and I prefer if we can get other independent solutions(not linked to the parameters of the phone user.).

Comment: No new independent methods ?